# Multiselection of cells with muose and copy of TableView using JAVAFX

Tags: uitableview, javafx, mouseevent, mouselistener, tablecolumn

I have a `TableView` which is editable and multiple selection enabled. I wish to enter new data to some columns and rows. Then I wish to select using mouse and press `CTRL-C` to copy to clipboard.

I can use `column.setCellFactory (TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn ());` and my code works well for entering data like EXCEL. I could not select using mouse.

I read the reference [How can I select multiple cells in tableview with javafx only by mouse?](https://community.oracle.com/message/11334815#11334815). If I try to implement it I need to use

`final Callback<TableColumn<MyDataClass, String>, TableCell<MyDataClass, String>> myCellFactory =  new DragSelectionCellFactory ();
column.setCellFactory (myCellFactory);`.

Then I am unable to enter any data as CellFactory is different now..

How may I enter data like EXCEL and also select mouse and use `CTRL-C` to copy? Thanks for any help.

Comment: try this: [link](https://gist.github.com/Roland09/0c7e26a2e7f72584fc1d)

Comment: @negste, thanks. I have seen that post. I am searching mouse activation for selection of cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor the code in the link you provided so that it references another cell factory, and "decorates" the cells with the dragging functionality:

```
public class DragSelectionCellFactory<S,T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S,T>, TableCell<S,T>> {

    private final Callback<TableColumn<S,T>, TableCell<S,T>> factory ;

    public DragSelectionCellFactory(Callback<TableColumn<S,T>, TableCell<S,T>> factory) {
        this.factory = factory ;
    }

    public DragSelectionCellFactory() {
        this(col -> new TableCell<S,T>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty || item == null) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override  
    public TableCell<S,T> call(final TableColumn<S,T> col) {            
        TableCell<S,T> cell = factory.call(col);  
        cell.setOnDragDetected(event ->  {  
            cell.startFullDrag();  
            col.getTableView().getSelectionModel().select(cell.getIndex(), col);  
        });  
        cell.setOnMouseDragEntered(event -> {  
            col.getTableView().getSelectionModel().select(cell.getIndex(), col);  
        });
        return cell ;  
    }  

}
```

Then you can do

```
TableColumn<Person, String> column = ... 
column.setCellFactory(
    new DragSelectionCellFactory<Person, String>(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried. It gives some error "DragSelectionCellFactory does not take parameter".

Comment: @vegaonline worked fine for me. What, precisely, was the error you got?

Comment: It says that `DragSelectionCellFactory does not take parameter`.  The code is taking `public DragSelectionCellFactory() {` constructor and not the one with Callback? Should I define the Callback stuffs ` private final Callback<TableColumn<S,T>, TableCell<S,T>> factory ;`   in the caller code just before `column.setCellFactory(...);`?

Comment: Well `DragSelectionCellFactory` clearly does take a parameter (it's not clear whether you mean the compiler is complaining about the constructor parameter, or the type parameter, but it takes both). So the compiler is somehow not seeing your new version of `DragSelectionCellFactory`: maybe you didn't save it, or maybe you have the wrong version imported? Again, I tested this and it worked just fine.

Comment: My Dear and Respected James, I am grateful to you. it was not saved. Thanks a lot for caring and guiding a beginner like me.